# Save DTO in Alpakka Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, akka, akka-stream, alpakka

Hi I create my own Connector of Cassandra using the datastax drivers. But I´m facing some Memory leaks issues, so I start considering another solutions like Alpakka de lightbend which has a Cassandra connector.

But after check the poor documentation I´m changing my mind, since it´s just using the connector with CQLSH queries, and in my case I manage DTO objects.

Anybody knows any documentation where I can see if Alpakka cassandra manage the save of DTO´s with consistency level?.

This code is from my current connector. I would like to achieve something similar.

```
private void updateCreateEntry(DTO originalDto, Mapper cassandraMapper) {
    ConsistencyLevel consistencyLevel = ((DTOCassandra) originalDto).getConsistencyLevel();
    //.- For writing we set the consistency level to quorum
    cassandraMapper.save(originalDto, Option.consistencyLevel(consistencyLevel != null ? consistencyLevel : DEFAULT_CONSISTENCY_LEVEL));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, presently the Cassandra connector within Alpakka is quite thin. If you need a richer support for your DTO, you could choose a richer client like [Phantom](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom).

There are excellent examples on how to use Phantom - check [this one](https://github.com/thiagoandrade6/cassandra-phantom) out for instance. Once you have created you model, Phantom will give you a `def store[T](t: T): Future[ResultSet]` function to insert data.

You can feed calls to these function to a `mapAsync(n)` combinator to make use of them in your Akka Stream.

Comment: Thanks!, I´ll take a look